# VueJS - render component only once

Tags: typescript, vue.js, singleton, vue-component

Is it possible to have a component that would only ever be rendered/instantiated once and the same instance could be used by other components?

I'm using the [npm Google Maps library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/googlemaps) in my project, and I want to have a single map instance rather than having to render it every time, which is using a lot of memory.

The below code shows the object that I'd like to be instantiated only once, as part of the component:

```
private googleMap: google.maps.Map;

    mounted() {
        this.googleMap = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), myMap.options);
    }
```

Comment: Render it in the root component e.g. App.vue

Answer (score 2):

**Instantiating component once** and **Rendering component once** are two different things.

**Rendering component once** is meaningless to think about. Render function will always be called whenever any `prop` or `instance` property is changed.

**Instantiating component once** is a very common scenario. Components like snackbar, dialog box, alert notifiers are often instantiated once.

To instantiate component once, there are two things you can do. First, make this component child of root instance or somewhere at the top of a component hierarchy like:

```
// Root Instance Template
<app-component>
    <header></header>
    <router-view></router-view>
    <google-map></google-map>
</app-component>
```

Next option is to manually instantiate and mount this component alongside the root Vue instance. Then, inject this component into your application hierarchy. You can do something like:

```
const mapComp = new Vue({ name: 'google-map' })
    .$mount(document.querySelector('.map'));

// Pass mapComp to rootInstance which can then inject into children component.
const rootInstance = new Vue({ /* options */, mapComp })
    .$mount(document.querySelector('.app'));
```

There are pros and cons of both the approaches but generally, the first approach should be preferred.

Comment: Thanks for your answer

Answer (score 1):

use [vuex store](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/) to store your `googleMap` object and pass a reference to it to your component as [props](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html) (recommended). that way, you can render your component a few times, but their `googleMap` prop will refer to your single `googleMap` object in the store.

i dont think its possible in vuejs to render a single component in different places in your app.

Comment: Thanks for your answer